# Variable not incrementing at end of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that loops over some cells and performs some calculations. Basically I set a value to a variable as a starting point...and that number is suppose to increment after it goes over each cell. The math and everything is working as desired, but the variable is not incrementing which is making everything wrong. It is only capturing the first value (which is 5.00 in my example below). Here is my function:

```
$(function percentSpace() {
  var theIndexer = 20;
  var x = $('#rackPlan0 > tbody > tr.categorySub > td:not(:first-child,:last-child)');
  x.each(function() {
    var a = $('#rackPlan1 > tbody > tr:last-child > td:nth-child(' + theIndexer + ')');
    var b = $(this);
    var c = parseFloat(a.text(), 10) || 0;
    console.log(theIndexer);
    var d = parseFloat(b.text(), 10) || 0;
    var perc = parseFloat((d / c) * 100);
    $(this).html(perc.toFixed(0)).append('%');
  });
  theIndexer++;
})
```

theIndexer is not incrementing...not sure why at this very moment...

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/92dta32v/4/) for the complete example (be sure to scroll to the right to see the other table). Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your increment is not inside the loop. https://jsfiddle.net/92dta32v/5/

Comment: Also your incremental variable is redundant as the `each()` handler function takes the index of the current iteration as a parameter

Comment: In addition to what @RoryMcCrossan said, this looks like an abuse of `:nth-child`. Why not just select the other set of `td` elements, and access them by index?

Comment: hmm appears I am going about this all wrong then...basically what I am trying to achieve is take the initial values in the bottom table (proto a, b, etc) and divide them by their grand total proto from the top table...

Comment: squint mind providing an example sir?

Comment: You want the result to go in the bottom table in the same row where the data is coming from in that table?

Comment: exactly, that value in that cell dividing by the grand value in the top table

Comment: `rackPlan0` has two rows with the class `.categorySub`. How should that relate to the one row in `rackPlan1`?

Comment: basically what i did was clone those two rows...strip stuff and append to the bottom table...the proto values in those rows need to be divided by their corresponding values in the grand total row in the top table

Comment: Oh, so you need to update both of those rows using the same division operation from the values in the single `rackPlan1` row?

Comment: yes sir, that is correct..i have tried a few different ways and failed...

Comment: Give this a try: https://jsfiddle.net/92dta32v/6/ Note that I made the first cell in each column in the `rackPlan0` table into a `th` instead of a `td`, so it was simpler to select the `td.subCat` cells. Note also that I selected the two rows that need to be updated, and first iterated over those. In that loop, there's a sub-loop of the cells in the current row. The `i` index should evenly correspond to the index of the cells from the `rackPlan1` table that were pre-selected. No need for an offset because I selected only those data rows with the `totalColumn` class.

Comment: I can't stay. Best of luck!

Comment: it does not appear the calculations are taking place...for example HEAD AND HAND (D23) %SPACE - PROTO A has a 1.0...it should be 1 /5, so that value there should be 20%

Comment: I had two typos. One was `subCat` instead of `catSub`, and the other was a wrong variable name. https://jsfiddle.net/92dta32v/7/ For future reference, reducing your code example down to a *minimal* example helps. That includes the HTML. Lots of extra markup there that doesn't pertain to the question.

Comment: ...and [here's another example](https://jsfiddle.net/92dta32v/8/) that is shorter and cleaner by passing a callback directly to `.text()`. This is also more efficient. I removed the radix parameter from `parseFloat`, since it does nothing in that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this ended up doing the job for me...thanks everyone...

```
   $(function percentSpace() {
                var theIndexer = 20;
                var x = $('#rackPlan0 > tbody > tr.categorySub > td:not(:first-child)');
                x.each(function () {    
                    var a = $('#rackPlan1 > tbody > tr:last-child > td:nth-child(' + theIndexer + ')');
                    var b = $(this);
                    var c = parseFloat(a.text(), 10) || 0;                        
                    var d = parseFloat(b.text(), 10) || 0;
                    var perc = parseFloat((d / c) * 100);
                    if ($(this).hasClass('catSub')) {
                        $(this).html(perc.toFixed(0)).append('%');
                        theIndexer++;
                    }
                    else if ($(this).hasClass('catFixP')) {
                        theIndexer = 20;
                    }
                });                    
            })
```

Comment: Sorry but that's still a nasty use of `:nth-child`. You should take better advantage of the classes you already defined when selecting elements.

Answer (score 1):

You must move the increment line inside the `each()` callback, otherwise it won't get executed until after that iterator. See example below:

```js
 $(function percentSpace() {
      var theIndexer = 20;
      var x = $('#rackPlan0 > tbody > tr.categorySub > td:not(:first-child,:last-child)');
      x.each(function() {
        var a = $('#rackPlan1 > tbody > tr:last-child > td:nth-child(' + theIndexer + ')');
        var b = $(this);
        var c = parseFloat(a.text(), 10) || 0;
        console.log(theIndexer);
        var d = parseFloat(b.text(), 10) || 0;
        var perc = parseFloat((d / c) * 100);
        $(this).html(perc.toFixed(0)).append('%');
      theIndexer++;
      });
      //output: indexer: 22
      console.log('indexer: ',theIndexer);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-style" id="rackPlan1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="nukeMe">
      <th>Category Group</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Proto S</th>
      <th>Fixture Points</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="nukeMe" style="display: none;">
      <td class="catGrp">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="category">HEAD AND HAND (D23)</td>
      <td class="protoS">0.50</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">567</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nukeMe" style="display: none;">
      <td class="catGrp">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="category">HEAD AND HAND (D23)</td>
      
      <td class="protoS">0.50</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">2,666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fineLineSub">
      <td class="sub0 subTotal">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="subTotal">HEAD AND HAND (D23)</td>
      <td class="subTotal">0.50</td>
      <td class="flFixP">3,233</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="categorySub">
      <td class="catSub">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="catSub">HEAD AND HAND (D23) TOTAL</td>
      <td class="catSub">0.50</td>
      <td class="catFixP">3,233</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nukeMe" style="display: none;">
      <td class="catGrp">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="category">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="protoS">0.00</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">582</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nukeMe" style="display: none;">
      <td class="catGrp">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="category">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="protoS">0.00</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">2,793</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fineLineSub">
      <td class="sub0 subTotal">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="subTotal">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="subTotal">0.00</td>
      <td class="flFixP">3,375</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nukeMe" style="display: none;">
      <td class="catGrp">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="category">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="protoS">0.50</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">588</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nukeMe" style="display: none;">
      <td class="catGrp">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="category">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="protoS">0.50</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">2,755</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fineLineSub">
      <td class="sub0 subTotal">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="subTotal">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="subTotal">0.50</td>
      <td class="flFixP">3,343</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nukeMe" style="display: none;">
      <td class="catGrp">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="category">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="protoS">1.00</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">587</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nukeMe" style="display: none;">
      <td class="catGrp">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="category">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="protoS">1.00</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">2,766</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fineLineSub">
      <td class="sub0 subTotal">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="subTotal">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="subTotal">1.00</td>
      <td class="flFixP">3,353</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nukeMe" style="display: none;">
      <td class="catGrp">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="category">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="protoS">0.00</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">537</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nukeMe" style="display: none;">
      <td class="catGrp">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="category">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="protoS">0.00</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">2,594</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fineLineSub">
      <td class="sub0 subTotal">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="subTotal">SWIMWEAR (D23)</td>
      <td class="subTotal">0.00</td>
      <td class="flFixP">3,131</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="categorySub">
      <td class="catSub">SEASONAL</td>
      <td class="catSub">SWIMWEAR (D23) TOTAL</td>
      <td class="catSub">1.50</td>
      <td class="catFixP">13,202</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="totalRacks">
      <td class="catGrp">GRAND TOTAL</td>
      <td class="category"></td>
      <td class="totalColumn">2.00</td>
      <td class="totalFixP">16,435</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table class="table-style" id="rackPlan0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Store Trait</th>
      <th>Proto A</th>
      <th>Proto S</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="storeCount">
      <td>Store Ct</td>
      <td class="protoA">5</td>
      <td class="protoS">3</td>
      <td class="totalRow">3,873</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="runningStore">
      <td class="totalText">Running Store Ct</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>3,873</td>
      <td class="totalRow">3,873</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allocatedRacks">
      <td>Allocated Racks</td>
      <td class="protoA">10</td>
      <td class="protoS">1</td>
      <td class="totalRow">106</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="overUnder">
      <td>Over/Under</td>
      <td>-5</td>
      <td>-5</td>
      <td class="catSub">0.50</td>
      <td class="catFixP">20%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="categorySub">
      <td class="catSub">SWIMWEAR (D23) %SPACE</td>
      <td class="catSub">4.00</td>
      <td class="catSub">1.50</td>
      <td class="catFixP">80%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```